# xslt: parsing text with tag

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml like this:

```
<main>
 text1 <tag>2</tag> text3
</main>
```

should be transformed via XSLT in:

```
<newMain>
 text1 <tag2>2</tag2>text3
</newMain>
```

but I don't know how to get it.
Can you help me?

Thanks

Rand

Comment: Do you want to do this for this particular case? Or does the 2 in main2 gets its value from the tag content?

Comment: sorry my fault: main2 and '2' are not related in any way. I changed the xml above.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="main | tag">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}2">
    <xs:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

should suffice if you simply want to append "2" to the name of the elements. If you want to take the number for element "tag" from the contents then do e.g.

```
    <xsl:template match="main">
      <xsl:element name="{name()}2">
        <xs:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tag">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}{.}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: sorry my fault: main2 and '2' are not related in any way. I changed the xml above.

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:reps>
  <rep old="main" new="newMain"/>
  <rep old="tag" new="tag2"/>
 </my:reps>

 <xsl:variable name="vReps" select="document('')/*/my:reps/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "*[name() = document('')/*/my:reps/*/@old]">

 <xsl:element name="{$vReps[@old = name(current())]/@new}">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
 </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<main>
 text1 <tag>2</tag> text3
</main>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<newMain>
 text1 <tag2>2</tag2> text3
</newMain>
```